# Polygon to Point in GeoPandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, geometry-conversion

I want to convert a shapefile from polygon to point:

```
pfile = pathtofile
file = gpd.read_file(pfile) #it is a polygon
```

Searched this site but didn't find anything similar:
http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html

Comment: Try GeoSeries.centroid. Basically what you have to do is calculate the centroid of the polygon and then store it into another variable.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify if you want one point, a multipoint, or many points.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the centroid of the polygons as  Ahsan Mukhtar says

**The polygons**

```
import geopandas as gpd
polys = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")
polys.head()
       POLY_NUM  Zn  Pb                         geometry
 0          24  10   0  POLYGON ((-716632.5126561673 -954202.638843462
 1          25  30  34  POLYGON ((-716623.8860221611 -954167.954016855
 2          26   5  55  POLYGON ((-716669.4794148145 -954153.082579828
 3          27  50  30  POLYGON ((-716573.0498599194 -954131.716264446
 4          28  80  67  POLYGON ((-716600.4004366234 -954260.332832906
```

[image]

**Centroids of the polygons**

```
# copy GeoDataFrame
points = polys.copy()
# change geometry 
points['geometry'] = points['geometry'].centroid
points.head()
       POLY_NUM  Zn  Pb                        geometry
 0          24  10   0  POINT (-716588.6708054555 -954243.4902445012)
 1          25  30  34  POINT (-716569.9936684616 -954200.8100592281)
 2          26   5  55  POINT (-716657.9447893198 -954169.1795523901)
 3          27  50  30  POINT (-716546.9534786827 -954140.7322584245)
 4          28  80  67  POINT (-716581.1026726362 -954286.1981425789)
```

[image]

But you can also use the exterior coordinates of the polygons to obtain **MultiPoints** as Vince says

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
points2 = polys.copy()
points2.geometry = points2.geometry.apply(lambda x: MultiPoint(list(x.exterior.coords)))
points2.head()
       POLY_NUM  Zn  Pb                        geometry
 0          24  10   0  (POINT (-716632.5126561673 -954202.6388434628)...
 1          25  30  34  (POINT (-716623.8860221611 -954167.954016855),...
 2          26   5  55  (POINT (-716669.4794148145 -954153.0825798288)...
 3          27  50  30  (POINT (-716573.0498599194 -954131.7162644463)...
 4          28  80  67  (POINT (-716600.4004366234 -954260.3328329064)...
```

[image]

You can also split the exterior coordinates into **multiples points**. For that you need a new GeoDataFrame (more points than polygons)

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
col = polys.columns.tolist()
print(col)
[u'POLY_NUM_B', u'Zn', u'Pb', 'geometry']
# new GeoDataFrame with same columns
nodes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=col)
# Extraction of the polygon nodes and attributes values from polys and integration into the new GeoDataFrame
for index, row in polys.iterrows():
    for j in list(row['geometry'].exterior.coords): 
        nodes = nodes.append({'POLY_NUM': int(row['POLY_NUM']), 'Pb':row['Pb'],'Zn':row['Zn'], 'geometry':Point(j) },ignore_index=True)
nodes.head()
       POLY_NUM  Zn  Pb                        geometry
 0         24  10  0  POINT (-716632.5126561673 -954202.6388434628)
 1         24  10  0   POINT (-716599.344199169 -954224.8253932064)
 2         24  10  0  POINT (-716538.7964301996 -954240.9772354551)
 3         24  10  0  POINT (-716529.3520701742 -954273.9782994529)
 4         24  10  0  POINT (-716550.9210327187 -954269.8358586552)
```

[image]