# How to create a copy of a geodataframe switching polygons for centroids (points)?

Tags: python, geopandas, centroids

I'd like to take an existing geopandas geodataframe (polygon) and create a copy, retaining all attributes of the first geodataframe but swapping out each feature's polygon geometry for its centroid.

Here's the part in question.  It is one tiny helper method in a large-ish class; the geopackage logic is the only thing I'm unfamiliar with and am not sure how to make work.  I have it all working using arcpy, but would like to have an open source version as well.

```
# geopandas has been imported as gpd
def to_gpkg(self, outfile, lyrname):
    if len(self.feats) > 0:  # geojson objects
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(self.geojson['features'])
        new_gdf = gdf[gdf.centroid]  # How to express this line?
        for idx, d in [gdf, new_gdf]:
            d.to_file(outfile, driver='GPKG', layer=f'{lyrname}_{idx}')
```

This yields `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Point'`

Comment: Possible already answered or at least will give you a lead: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302430/polygon-to-point-in-geopandas

Comment: That gave me enough to get it done, thanks.  Should I leave the question open for posterity?